# require_once repeats

Tags: php, jquery, require-once

I am trying to email myself the client's browser data **once**; however, the page the require_once is on has a jQuery gallery changing images and it seems... that the php is running with every image transition.

I tried to prevent the repeat with this, but that too fails

```
 $currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
 if ($execute <> 5) { require_once 'send_mail.inc'; }
```

Where $execute is set to 5 in send_mail.inc.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you need the data 1 time forever or for each page visit? You could try a cookie. or use the Session like below as Rob has stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require_once is per runtime. If you have a bunch of ajax requests, each is filled by a new runtime. You need a way to persist something. You could use sessions to do that. Store a fact about the first request in session and send the email. On subsequent requests, do not send the email.